Update a column present in multiple tables in Entity Framework Core
I am using Entity Framework Core version 8.
I have multiple tables (declared as DBSet<TableClass>) present in the DbContext, each with a column OwnersCache.
I would like to update the values in the OwnersCache column of all the tables without specifying the table names explicitly.
How to implement this with the DbContext?
To be more precise, I have a variable dbContext. The substring Name1 in the OwnersCache column of all the database tables should be replaced with NewName1.
Thanks

If this is a one-time action you better do it in SQL. If not: normalize the database schema and change all these OwnersCache columns into a FK to a little table that contains the actual value. Then only one simple update is required.

Hi, an element can have many owners in the DB. So while displaying all the elements in a page, I need to join all the owners for each element which results in performance and time overhead.
Having a cache column avoids table joins every time the elements display page is loaded.
This was the reasoning for the question I posted.

Then you have an issue that you should solve on the database level. Database performance should not suffer badly by adding a join to the query. Check if there are proper indexes. You should not need this redundant and error-prone column.

I agree that it's redundant but this column is for display purposes only
